# How to turn off date like linking in Joomla 1.6

Tags: php, joomla

Currently my links look like

```
index.php/2011-05-04-06-52-18
```

How do I turn this off, and use the linkage like in old Joomla 1.5 with `/about-us`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable SEF Urls and mod-rewrite in the server configuration.

Here is a Video :
http://www.webmaster-tips.net/Joomla-1.6/Video-Tutorials/How-to-enable-SEF-Search-Engine-Friendly-URLs-in-joomla-1.6.html

And a description of the options:
http://www.finishjoomla.com/blog/28/joomla-16-seo-recommended-settings/